# How will I write my condition that will determine the data if it is a Dog or a Cat and will be able to display it under its respective column?

Tags: php

```
Customer's Name | Dog | Cat
Glenn           |  1  |
Mark            |     |  1
Jim             |  2  |  3
```

How to identify my count if it belongs to Dog column or in Cat?

```php
<?php
require_once 'DbConnect.php';
$db = new DbConnect;
$conn = $db->connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Customers_Name,Type, Count(Qunatity) AS count FROM dbo.Pet");
$stmt->execute();
$count = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>"'.$row['Customers_Name'].'"</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    if ($row['type'] == "Dog"){
        echo '<td>' . $row['count']. '</td>' ;
    }else {
        echo '<td>' . $row['count']. '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: what you are getting in your current output also update it in you question

Comment: all the counts(quantity) are in dog column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility. It adds an empty cell for cats when it's a dog, and an empty cell for dogs when it's a cat.

```php
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Customers_Name'].'</td>';
    if ($row['type'] == "Dog") {
        echo '<td>' . $row['count']. '</td><td></td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td></td><td>' . $row['count']. '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here's another option, using slightly different logic, plus a different way of creating the HTML. I personally find this to be more readable, plus it is more easily extensible if you later decide to add birds, rabbits, etc.

```php
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row['Customers_Name'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['Type'] == 'Dog' ? $row['count'] : '' ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['Type'] == 'Cat' ? $row['count'] : '' ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endwhile;
```

Note that if you have a customer with both dogs and cats (as your desired output would seem to indicate), then neither of these is sufficient, and you'll need to do more work to merge multiple rows of results into a single table row.

Here's a version (untested) that combines all the rows with the same names, then outputs it all at once. If you have a lot of data, this will not be a great approach, and you'd be better off either changing your database structure, or at the very least ordering your query by name and adapting this to output a row whenever you get a different name.

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    if (!array_key_exists($row['Customers_Name'], $rows)) {
        $rows[ $row['Customers_Name'] ] = [];
    }
    $rows[ $row['Customers_Name'] ][ $row['Type'] ] = $row['count'];
}

foreach ($rows as $name => $counts):
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $name ?></td>
        <td><?= $counts['Dog'] ?? '' ?></td>
        <td><?= $counts['Cat'] ?? '' ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: If customer have both dog and cat, it adds up another row of the same customer name. it wont merge in just 1 row.

Comment: Yes, I stated that limitation in my answer. But that seemed like a bit different issue than what you were struggling with, and I wasn't sure if maybe showing the solution for the partial case would help you get over the hump. If I have some time later today, I'll come back and update with a more thorough answer for that.

Comment: okay, thank you. I'll wait later for more help from you.